# IdentityServer4: what about the "sub" scope?

Tags: openid, identityserver4

I've got running up an IdentityServer4. When I now try to authenticate now, I get the following error:

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator[0]
      Requested scope not allowed: sub
```

When I get the open id document from /.well-known/openid-configuration/ I get as supported scope:

```
["address","phone","openid","email","profile","api1","offline_access"]
```

There is no "sub" scope as supported_scope in it.

Here is the complete config document:

```
{"issuer":"http://localhost:5000","jwks_uri":"http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks","authorization_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize","token_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/token","userinfo_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/endsession","check_session_iframe":"http://localhost:5000/connect/checksession","revocation_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/revocation","introspection_endpoint":"http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect","frontchannel_logout_supported":true,"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"scopes_supported":["openid","address","phone","openid","email","profile","api1","offline_access"],"claims_supported":["sub","address","phone_number","phone_number_verified","email","email_verified","name","family_name","given_name","middle_name","nickname","preferred_username","profile","picture","website","gender","birthdate","zoneinfo","locale","updated_at"],"response_types_supported":["code","token","id_token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"response_modes_supported":["form_post","query","fragment"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","client_credentials","refresh_token","implicit","password"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post"],"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"]}
```

I tried the following on startup:

```
app.UseIdentity();
app.UseIdentityServer();

var allowedScopes = new []{"address","phone","email","profile","api1","offline_access", "sub"};
var identityAuthOptions = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions();
identityAuthOptions.AllowedScopes =  allowedScopes;
identityAuthOptions.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
identityAuthOptions.AutomaticChallenge = true;        
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(identityAuthOptions);
```

My configurations for the IdentityServer looks as follows:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddOperationalStore(options => 
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PersistedGrants"), 
        builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName)))
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources());


services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Where the Config class is this:

```
public class Config
    {
        // scopes define the resources in your system
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Address(),
                new IdentityResources.Phone(),
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "Main API", new[]{ "sub" })
            };
        }

        // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "actionCommunity",
                    AllowPlainTextPkce = true,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AllowRememberConsent = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                    RedirectUris = {
                        "http://localhost:3333/login-success",
                        "http://localhost:3000/login-success",
                        "http://localhost:3000/auth.html"
                    },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = {
                        "api1", "sub",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true
                }
            };
        }

        public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return new List<TestUser>
            {
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "1",
                    Username = "testUser",
                    Password = "testPassword",

                    Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("name", "Testuser"),
                        new Claim("website", "https://www.testuser.de")
                    }
                },
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "2",
                    Username = "bob",
                    Password = "password",

                    Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("name", "Bob"),
                        new Claim("website", "https://bob.com")
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

So: whatever I try, I can't manage to get the strange 'sub' scope up.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the claimType while creating APiResource.

```
   public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "Main API", new[]{ "sub" })
        };
    }
```

Following is the signature of constructor:

```
public ApiResource(string name, string displayName, IEnumerable<string> claimTypes)
```

You can add scope by referring the following snippet taken from IdentityServer4 documents:

```
// expanded version if more control is needed
    new ApiResource
    {
        Name = "api2",

        // secret for using introspection endpoint
        ApiSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },

        // include the following using claims in access token (in addition to subject id)
        UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.Email }
        },

        // this API defines two scopes
        Scopes =
        {
            new Scope()
            {
                Name = "api2.full_access",
                DisplayName = "Full access to API 2",
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "api2.read_only",
                DisplayName = "Read only access to API 2"
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer the following link to more details:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/configuration/resources.html#defining-api-resources

Comment: Okay, I will try it in the noon. Does this code snippet add the sub claim? What is this sub claim, and for what is it?

Comment: Refer the comment from @Scott Brady about sub claim. you can add it by setting UserClaim in the scope or resource `UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Subject},`

Answer (score 1):

`sub` is not a scope, but a claim. It is included with the `openid` scope (and therefore every identity token).

Since there is no such scope configured IdentityServer, that's also why you are getting the error. If you remove the `sub` scope from your request it should work.